# How to measure user trust in crowd-sourced data?

Tags: correlation, algorithms

I am developing an application that will feed itself from users, all data will come from users crowdsourcing it with GPS positions. Said data must be pretty accurate or else my application will not work, not at all.

I've setup a trust index subsystem where each point of data has as a trust index, and said index is bumped up each time data with similar characteristics is uploaded, in other words, if point A is located at 4.33, -75.33 (Made up point) and another user uploads a 4.25, -75.30 (B) point, i can be sure to bump the trust index for A instead of creating another point altogether (Assuming the physical distance from A to B is 5 meters as a maximum).

Any suggestions on how to enhance this algorithm? Any other algorithm i could use to cross-validate all the new data with previous data? Any paper i can read about this topic?

As for more information, this trust index will be used to create different routes (as in sets of points) to navigate a map so the system can take in account only those points with certain minimum trust index or outright discard points that never got the minimum trust in a period of time from the database to save space.

Comment: Are the points labelled? That is, if user B uploads a point, do you know whether it's supposed to be the same point that user A uploaded earlier or another point?

Comment: No, they are not labeled per se, but they are supposed to be pooled in certain groups. If user A uploads a point in the gA group and user B uploads in the gB group, even if the points are the same their trust index will not be bumped as they are not in the same group. If they are in the same group, a simple equality test (With a bit of tolerance mixed in) will account to determine if two points are the same.

Comment: Ok, that makes it more complicated. Is there a particular aspect of your current algorithm that you're unhappy with, or are you just looking for possible alternatives?

Comment: I am happy but i am looking for alternatives or enhancements to my approach, a bit more security wont hurt.